# Spring @Transaction rolling back on completion of an action method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

I have a method defined for an action button in JSF in the backing bean. I am using Hibernate as the ORM. I am able to save the fresh data. But when I try to update the same data, a transaction roll back exception is thrown

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{itemModificationBean.saveData('0','IM')}: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
   at
```

I have no interface implemented for the method and it is being called and defined in the backing bean itself.

Is there any way to find out what is going wrong ?....

Any help would be appreciated

Let me know if any more details are required to elaborate more on the issue

**Backing Bean**

ItemBackingBean action method

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public String saveData(String action, String app) throws WFException {

    setSaveOrSubmitStatus(action);
    setCurrentApp(app);
    //DB operations
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    return requestNo
}
```

**The component**

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.save}" type="submit" id="modifySav"
                        process="@form @this"
                        action="#{itemModificationBean.saveData('0','IM')}"
                        rendered="#{itemAttributeBean.getRenderedValue('modifySav')}"
                        update="@([id$=form]) @([id$=collectionTab])  @([id$=itemRequestDetailsGrid]) @([id$=saveDialogItemMod])"
                        style="float:right;" />
```

Comment: Do you have some Java code?

Comment: Its a pretty big method as its a legacy code. So I have added the essential parts

Comment: Can you include the complete implementation of backing bean? Also, can you catch the exception in the backingBean and print the stacktrace and include that as well? Apparently the update seems to fail. Also can you include the hibernate entity definition?

Comment: Totally not JSF related!

Comment: All the pointers helped. Finally figured out that it was due to an exception which was not properly thrown from the legacy code. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

From your stacktrace it is said that

> transaction has been marked as roll-back only

I would suggest these steps:

1. Determine, where the transaction is started. As you may have different `transactionPropagation` strategies, you need to find out the first place where it is started.
2. Examine all the methods that uses same transaction context (all methods where transaction was propogated during execution) and try to get exceptions which causes transaction to roll-back: check transaction rolling back policies of your container. Spring for example rolling back when runtime exceptions occured (check [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings)).
3. Identify exception and reasons for them and then act appropriatly.

From what I see from the qestion details it could be methods that are called from your backing bean `saveData` method which are in the same transactional context. So update itself may work as it should be but previous method calls already marked current transaction as roll-back only. Check theirs transaction propagation strategies.

I assume that some of the methods before database operation rolled back transaction by some exception or explicitly marked transaction as rolled-back only. Those methods don't throw exception and that's why the program flow continue to database operation method call but it can't be done in the same transactional context.